# wso2esb with a registry based on scm

Tags: svn, wso2-esb

Is it possible to mount an external registry path that is from scm path. I have used scm in registry to mount svn to it's path. Now i am trying to use wso2esb to mount that point in the registry.

The mounting all looks ok, the folder structure is present but there is no content in any of the files in the esb. It looks ok in the registry i can view files but not in the esb. There is very little documentation on scm.

Thanks if you can help

Answer (score 0):

this was yet another wso2 bug. this works in version 4.5.0 of esb with version 4.5.0 of the registry. it does not work with 4.5.1 or 4.6.0 of esb.

its amazing how many things break when a new version is released

Answer (score 0):

This is due to bug in G-Reg 4.5.1.

[1]https://wso2.org/jira/browse/REGISTRY-1607

Thanks

Ajith